# Execution python cron job on machines that has no "pip3 install" installed on them

Tags: python-3.x

The below code does a simple select query . 
and I need this code to be executed on other Linux machines, but they don't have pymysql istalled .
they also dont have pip3 installed .
I can install all this manually , but those machined are getting redeployed every night and so I need to find a way to automatically install all the libs needed before the script execution.

I thought of "Requests.txt" , but again I dont have pip3 install .
I wanted to install pip3 using "Curl" but I don't have pyCurl installed . 
I was thinking maybe creating some Linux bash script and call it before execution , but I hope there is some other more convenient way 
So need some help in finding a solution

```
import pymysql


connection = pymysql.connect(host='172.0.0.10',
                         port=3333,
                         user='myDB',
                         password='********',
                         db='dbName'
                         )


def SelectFromDB(SelectLine):


# Read a single record
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = SelectLine
    try:
        result = cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
    except pymysql.Error as e:


res = SelectFromDB("SELECT ID FROM Customers ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1")[0]
print("select res is " + str(res))
```

Comment: You can try `easy_install` which should be installed with default Python. The other way would be to change deployment process to include pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do when I need to execute some scripts with crontab is to put all the required setup inside a bash script and then executing in the crontab, just before executing the Python script.

It is a very clean way to do it, and in case you need to change something in the setup you can do it directly by changing the bash script, instead of changing the crontab.